# Can't use models on live site LAMP Codeigniter

Tags: sql, configuration, lamp, ownership

I have a website that I recently moved to a live LAMP version on a linux VM. Using codeigniter, I have the model trying to do a simple register to the SQL database. I don't get an error in the error log except for the ones i told my code to give. But I do get a 500 Internal Server error in the browser's console. The code in the model is:

public function register($email, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $gender, $birthday){

```
$salt = $this->generateSalt();

$password = $this->hash($password, $salt);

$data = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'salt' => $salt, 'first_name' => $first_name,
    "last_name" => $last_name, 'gender' => $gender, "birthday" => $birthday);

error_log("befoer load");
$this->load->database();
error_log("after load");
if($this->db->insert('users', $data)){
    $this->loginById($this->db->insert_id());
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

}

it doesn't get to the after load line in the error log but it does get to the before load.

I think this could be a problem with the database.config so just in case here it is without the username or password(I've like checked those 1000 times):

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'http://130.184.99.114/',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'meetings',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

Now then, I think this is a problem with my config file, or the owners on something. I've never released a live site before so I have no clue what to look for. Any advice on this would be very appreciated!

Comment: setup `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` and `display_errors = On` in php.ini and see server `error.log`

Comment: That didn't get me any more information. :(